# Can I suppress warnings in a Cython-generated file (but not others)?

Tags: c++, clang, cython

I'm using -Wall (with clang) and the project contains Cython sources, which are compiled to C.

I'm getting warnings for the generated code:

```
ast.cpp:16802:28: warning: unused function '__Pyx_PyObject_AsString' [-Wunused-function]
static CYTHON_INLINE char* __Pyx_PyObject_AsString(PyObject* o) {
```

(10 of these)

Is there a way to suppress them while still having the warning active for other parts of the project?

Comment: What build system are you using for compiling the extension module?  Python's distutils?  Make?  CMake?  SCons?  You'll have to tell clang to ignore these warnings with `-Wno-unused-function`, and make sure this flag is passed to just the Cython extension modules.